# reading jpeg file as a unsigned char array

Tags: c++, io, jpeg

I'm trying to making a video stream using jpeg files using next project:
https://www.medialan.de/usecase0001.html

they are using jpegsamples according the following header and source file.

jpegsmaples.h:

```
#ifndef JPEGSAMPLES_H
#define JPEGSAMPLES_H

#define KJpegCh1ScanDataLen 32
#define KJpegCh2ScanDataLen 56

extern char JpegScanDataCh1A[];
extern char JpegScanDataCh1B[];

extern char JpegScanDataCh2A[];
extern char JpegScanDataCh2B[];
```

jpegsamples.cpp:

```
#include "jpegsamples.h"

// RGB JPEG images as RTP payload - 48x32 pixel
char JpegScanDataCh1A[KJpegCh1ScanDataLen] =
{
    static_cast<char>(0xf8), static_cast<char>(0xbe),
    static_cast<char>(0x8a), static_cast<char>(0x28),
    static_cast<char>(0xaf), static_cast<char>(0xe5),
    static_cast<char>(0x33), static_cast<char>(0xfd),
    static_cast<char>(0xfc), static_cast<char>(0x0a),
    static_cast<char>(0x28), static_cast<char>(0xa2),
    static_cast<char>(0x80), static_cast<char>(0x0a),
    static_cast<char>(0x28), static_cast<char>(0xa2),
    static_cast<char>(0x80), static_cast<char>(0x0a),
    static_cast<char>(0x28), static_cast<char>(0xa2),
    static_cast<char>(0x80), static_cast<char>(0x0a),
    static_cast<char>(0x28), static_cast<char>(0xa2),
    static_cast<char>(0x80), static_cast<char>(0x0a),
    static_cast<char>(0x28), static_cast<char>(0xa2),
    static_cast<char>(0x80), static_cast<char>(0x3f),
    static_cast<char>(0xff), static_cast<char>(0xd9)
};
char JpegScanDataCh1B[KJpegCh1ScanDataLen] =
{
    static_cast<char>(0xf5), static_cast<char>(0x8a),
    static_cast<char>(0x28), static_cast<char>(0xa2),
    static_cast<char>(0xbf), static_cast<char>(0xca),
    static_cast<char>(0xf3), static_cast<char>(0xfc),
    static_cast<char>(0x53), static_cast<char>(0x0a),
    static_cast<char>(0x28), static_cast<char>(0xa2),
    static_cast<char>(0x80), static_cast<char>(0x0a),
    static_cast<char>(0x28), static_cast<char>(0xa2),
    static_cast<char>(0x80), static_cast<char>(0x0a),
    static_cast<char>(0x28), static_cast<char>(0xa2),
    static_cast<char>(0x80), static_cast<char>(0x0a),
    static_cast<char>(0x28), static_cast<char>(0xa2),
    static_cast<char>(0x80), static_cast<char>(0x0a),
    static_cast<char>(0x28), static_cast<char>(0xa2),
    static_cast<char>(0x80), static_cast<char>(0x3f),
    static_cast<char>(0xff), static_cast<char>(0xd9)
};
```

I've already tried to read the binary data of the jpeg file into a char array according following code:

```
    std::ifstream Datafile("C:\test01.jpg", std::ios::binary);
    if(!Datafile.good())
        return;
    Datafile.seekg(0, std::ios::end);
    size_t filesize = (int)Datafile.tellg();
    Datafile.seekg(0);

    char * output = new char[filesize];
    if(Datafile.read((char *)output, filesize))
    {
        std::ofstream fout("def.jpeg", std::ios::binary);
        if(!fout.good())
            return;
        fout.write((char *)output, filesize);
    }
```

but this didn't work and didn't gave any error. the streaming client (VLC) was in a loop of trying to connect and receiving images.

First I want to be able to receive a image of the jpeg file like in next example:
[image: VLC Client connected example]

This should be doable by storing the data of the jpeg file in an char array like they did in the jpegsamples code.

EDIT:
There is no need to write a new file so i've edited the code I've already tried and added some more relevant code:

```
    std::ifstream Datafile("C:\\test01.jpg", std::ios::binary);
    if(!Datafile.good())
    {
        std::cout <<"error file"<<std::endl;
        return;
    }
    Datafile.seekg(0, std::ios::end);
    size_t filesize = (int)Datafile.tellg();
    Datafile.seekg(0);

    char * output = new char[filesize];

    char  * Samples1[2] = {output , output };
    char  * Samples2[2] = {output , output };
```

which resulted into next image:
[image: VLC Client connection with different code]
There is definitely something wrong with the data. I might need a jpeg I/O library?

Comment: OT: `"C:\test01.jpg"` you should escape the \ or just use / instead

Comment: On an unrelated note, if the variable `output` is of type `char*`, then you don't need to cast it to type `char*`. And when you need to cast, then don't use C-style casts, but [`reinterpret_cast`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/reinterpret_cast) instead.

Comment: It will not give error because you silently return on error without displaying any message.

Comment: *`new char[filesize]`* – didn't try to understand your code, but stop using `new[]`, please. Use a `std::vector<char unsigned>`.

Comment: If my first comment was still editable I would remove the OT part. I am pretty sure that is the issue now..

Comment: @drescherjm yes you were right that was an error. Now I can establish a connection between client and server, but there is no image. just a plain black screen.

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude thanks, that was some code I forgot to remove.

Comment: @drescherjm I don't get a black screen anymore. I've updated the question (read EDIT) and there I've updated the code. I've edited and added some relevant code (two lines). To end with, I've asked a final question if I need a jpeg I/O library instead of just reading the jpegs binaries.

Comment: basically I'm doubting that a jpeg file can just be binary read and presented as in jpegsamples.cpp without using a JPEG I/O, therefor I'm asking that final question and I'll report my results.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The values in jpegsamples.cpp are defined as JPEG images for RTP payload. This are not the same values as the raw data values in the jpeg file.

Therefore It is not possible to simple read the binary values of the file and use them for the RTP payload, without any calculation. I think goes behind the scope of this topic and this will 'answer' the question.

For more info about [the RTP payload format for JPEG images](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc2435)